# Site Design Suggestions

Tags: discussion

Now that we're in the public beta, we should probably start thinking about a site design. Since this is a Freelancing Q&A site, would any graphic designers be willing to donate a logo and/or layout? From what I understand, Stack Exchange has designers on staff to help with this ([source, #6](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)), but we can have our own ideas for how the site should appear.

Comment: Personally, it would be interesting if we incorporated the different aspects of freelancing into the logo (design, writing, etc.) That being said, design is not my forte (barely mezzo forte)

Comment: Out of interest what stage are we at currently?

Answer (score 2):

After using [Color Combos](http://www.colorcombos.com/), I came up with the following [color scheme](http://www.colorcombos.com/combomaker.html?design=circles&output_width=500&size_option=image&colors=4A7B6F,EEEEE7,CCDDDD,9EAEB3,242E35,B52A2A&background_color=FFFFFF&show_hex_flag=Y).

[image: Color Combination]

In addition, I think the main logo should be a picture of a piece of paper, perhaps appearing slightly crumpled, consisting of the lower-case "i". This would accentuate the fact that freelancing is done on one's own.

Comment: Hmm.. I actually really like that colour scheme. I looked at it yesterday and though "eh", but now I think it could fit well. I'll mess around a bit with one of the graduated sites' HTML in chrome inspector and see if i can make that scheme work, then show an example.

Comment: @Hiroto - What are your thoughts on [this font](http://www.dafont.com/champignon.font?text=freelancing) as part of the header?

Comment: I'm not a fan of that font at all. I'm not really a big fan of script fonts as a whole, come to think of it.